# How to make a single thread handle multiple clients (using sockets in the main thread)?

Tags: c, sockets

I have to write program for a server in C which has 3 ports listening. When multiple clients connect to one of the ports, it has to create only one thread which handles all the clients coming on the same port. How to make a single thread handle more than one client?

Comment: Multiplex.  `select`, `poll`, `epoll`.

Comment: Use non-blocking I/O (O_NONBLOCK) along with select or poll as @Duck suggested.

Comment: actually I want to create multiple threads and when clients come, they should get served by these previously created threads parrallely.